# Retrieve service closing time?

Tags: java, android

I want to restart my service with new data, what allows me to release every objects in service without making complicated communication between Fragment<>Service.

I tried this, everything works:

```
  if(isMyServiceRunning(PlayerService.class))
            {
                getActivity().stopService(intenx);
                positionTemp--;
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().startService(intenx);
                        positionTemp++;
                    }
                }, 500);

            }
            else{
                getActivity().startService(intenx);
            }
        }
    });
```

But I don't know if I should to worry about closing time in different devices? Is there possibility than service will be closing longer than 500ms? My Motorola takes 300ms to close service and then I can re-run it without problem.

Any advice? Communication with service isn't really easy, it's music player with almost 15 different controls, etc. I think that the easiest way is just stop current service and restart with new entry variables.

Answer (score 0):

That seems unnecessary, and it'll add a 500 ms lag to any user actions. A Service can accept multiple intents without stopping and starting again. Just handle each new intent in `onStartCommand()`. You don't need any complicated communication between the fragment and service; the fragment just needs to forward every request to the service and let the service do its thing. Although for a better UI you might need to bind to the service so it can update the UI based on the service's state.